# Where can I find a current list of touch-range spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, online-resources

I'm planning on making a wizard character that uses *Find Familiar*, so I need a list of current touch range spells (UA-included). Where can I look to find a list of touch-range spells?

Answer (score 11):

## Use [D&D Beyond's spell archive](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells)

You can filter by class, source, etc. and then sort those by Range to find all the touch spells.

Searches will be limited to freely available materials unless you have a D&D Beyond subscription or own the requisite books on D&D Beyond.

Caveat: It does seem like [D&D Beyond is only planning to include future UA and not past.](http://www.dndbeyond.com/posts/137-unearthed-arcana-content-on-d-d-beyond)

Comment: Dndbeyond won't have UA like the OP requested.

Comment: @DavidCoffron Yes, it does. It's under source choices.

Comment: Oh. I'm on mobile and didn't realize I could scroll. Derp

Comment: Interestingly there are no UA only spells yet. :)

Comment: @DavidCoffron Very strange, I feel like that may be a DB issue - but maybe Xanathar's brought all the new spells in that had been inside UAs.

Comment: It definitely isn't that. While many of the spells from [this UA](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/starter-spells) reappeared, not all of them. (Just to list one article with spells in, I don't remember if any others did). And certainly the [Modern Magic](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/modern-magic&ved=2ahUKEwigqYLmuPHZAhWH7YMKHW_7CtQQFjABegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw3rBT06v02ul5ZwaXl6fCcI) weren't added.

Comment: @DavidCoffron That was the first one I was going to check - so it looks like it's a bit buggy :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74643/discussion-between-nautarch-and-david-coffron).

Comment: @DavidCoffron: [DnDB only includes UA from Jan. 2018 and later](http://www.dndbeyond.com/posts/137-unearthed-arcana-content-on-d-d-beyond) with no public plans to bring the older stuff in too.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Yeah. I found that out from the dev stream on twitch. Thanks for an easier source though. :)